# NextJS auth0 useUser hook with other hooks - handling multiple isLoading best practices

Tags: next.js, loading, auth0, next.js13

I'm using Auth0 and NextJS.

Auth0 provides me the `useUser()` hook on the client which returns props like `{ user, isLoading, isError }`.

I'm also using `useSWR()` to get data on the client side, which also returns me props like `{ data, isLoading, isError }`.

What are the recommended approaches for handling multiple loading or error props on the client if I need to use them on the same page?

Things I've considered:

- Ignore one, prioritise the other. For example if there is an error getting the user, I probably can't get the client side data (as it depends on the user).
- Rename them during destructuring. E.g. `{ user, isLoading: userLoading }` and handle each case separately. (Seems potentially verbose if I need to do the same thing in multiple components.
- Some kind of further separation, and prop passing between components. This seems possible. But also feels like my components will end up coupled to their structure which I'd like to avoid.

What's the recommended approach for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can absolutely rename it, that's the way I do it on my apps. All my hooks return the 4 same values ({data, isLoading, error, reload})
and I just rename it according to the kind of data im dealing with.

```
   const {
    data: createUserPayoutData,
    isLoading: isCreateUserPayoutDataLoading,
    error: createUserPayoutDataError,
} = useCreateUserPayOut();
const {
    data: walletData,
    isLoading: isWalletDataLoading,
    error: walletDataError,
} = useGetUserWallet();
```